# How to write query using Joins and Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, twitter, relational-database

I have a SQL Server Database where I store tweets and it's relations.

I have the following tables:

- **tweets** (which has tweets properties, such as its id)
- **users** (which has users properties, such as its id)
- **hashtags** (which store the mentioned hashtags. It has an id and hashtag column, which stores the hashtag string)
- **searches** (this stores the search I have interest in, for example, if I want to search for the tweets talking about "cars", the search table has a row with a search_id and the search_word, which would be "cars").

I connect those using two one-to-many relational tables (**searches_tweets** and **hashtags_tweets**), connecting the id's of each table. These are the connections between those:

- searches - searches_tweets - tweets (searches_tweets has 2 columns: search_id and tweet_id)
- hashtags - hashtags_tweets - tweets (hashtags_tweets has 2 columns: hashtag_id and tweet_id)

First, I wanted to do the following query: I wanted to retrieve the amount of times a certain hashtag was mentioned in the tweets of a certain search. I achieved that by doing this:

```
SELECT TOP(100) hashtags.id, hashtags.hashtag, count(tweets.id) AS total_count FROM hashtags
JOIN hashtags_tweets ON hashtags_tweets.hashtag_id = hashtags.id
JOIN tweets ON tweets.id = hashtags_tweets.tweet_id
JOIN searches_tweets ON searches_tweets.tweet_id = tweets.id
WHERE searches_tweets.search_id = 1234
GROUP BY hashtags.id, hashtags.hashtag
ORDER BY total_count DESC
```

Now, I want to add a column which shows the amount of users that wrote this hashtag in their tweets (from the same search_id). I don't find a way to do this. I tried the following query:

```
SELECT TOP(100) hashtags.id, hashtags.hashtag, count(tweets.id) AS total_count, count(users.id) AS users_count 
FROM hashtags
JOIN hashtags_tweets ON hashtags_tweets.hashtag_id = hashtags.id
JOIN tweets ON tweets.id = hashtags_tweets.tweet_id
JOIN searches_tweets ON searches_tweets.tweet_id = tweets.id
JOIN users ON tweets.user_id = users.id
WHERE searches_tweets.search_id = 1234
GROUP BY hashtags.id, hashtags.hashtag,  users.id
ORDER BY total_count DESC
```

This query didn't work since `users_count` had the same value as `total_count`. How would you achieve this expected result?

Comment: If I follow you correctly, `count(DISTINCT users.id)`. And remove `users.id` from the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the distinct number of user you should use

```
SELECT TOP(100) hashtags.id, hashtags.hashtag, count(tweets.id) AS total_count, 
count(distinct users.id) AS users_count 
FROM hashtags
  ......

GROUP BY hashtags.id, hashtags.hashtag
```

and obviusly  .. you must remove the   users.id from the broup by clause..

Comment: Yes, and as @HoneyBadger said, also needed to remove users.id from the GROUP BY

Comment: @MarkJohnson  obvious  .. anyway answer  updated  with correct group by